# JPEG-2000: Can I dynamically resize an image without resampling?

Tags: performance, thumbnails, jpeg2000

One of the nice features of JPEG 2000 is that it's easy to downres an image -- just feed out fewer bytes.

Is there a similar way to scale the image, such that I could send a thumbnail using bytes in the full-size file, without resampling?

Comment: I was just about to ask this question myself...

Comment: Can't you just reduce the quality of compression, e.g. `-quality 30`? The quality is in dB, the higher the better, with 0 lossless and +inf maximum. http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=120931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, to resize you will still have to read the original size, resample to the new size, and then recompress.

You can write your file such that it has layers with powers-of-2 sizes, with a very small relative incremental increase in size, and extract those layers.